# Meaning of "Smiles Slip"

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, ambiguity, dialects

I don't quite understand something:

> [source](http://www.independent.co.uk/sport/football/news-and-comment/deaths-in-sao-paulo-arena-corinthians-stadium-collapse-add-to-worries-over-2014-world-cup-8968198.html)
>   Brazil will, in one form or another, be ready for the World Cup. But when it comes to hosting the tournament, those famous Brazilian ***smiles*** may already be ***slipping***.

What does "***slip***" mean in this context?  I cannot find a good definition in dictionaries.

Comment: Means just what the dictionary says. The *smiles slipping* is a metaphorical use, not an idiom or set phrase.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common idiom: a smile can slip from someone's face, meaning that they are no longer as happy about something as they used to be, or that their smile was false.